# how to create an arrays from rows using Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

Hi guys i need your help, so i have an array

```
a   b   c   n
1   1   2   4
1   3   2   6
1   6   0   7
```

and i want to create another array form each rows of my array, see picture below.
[image]

I tried using this code:

assuming that my data is located at array M so,

```
for x=1:10
   d = M(:,4)/(M(:,1) + M(:,2) + M(:,3) + x)
end
```

but it doesn't give my desired output

in excel you just only write the equation and drag it down, in you will have the answer but i don't know how to do it in matlab, i think we could use for loop. thanks.

PLEASE SEE THE RED BOX THAT'S MY DESIRED OUTPUT

Comment: How do you get 10 values out of three rows? I assume the formula is repeated for **each row**? Do you also mean that your input data has ten rows even though you are only showing three? I would think so based on the code you posted...? And what is `d` in your code?

Comment: because your x = 1 to 10, meaning you will create another array of x having a size of 10x1. and another array of y which is proportional to the values of x, a,b,c, and n, so that in the end you will have a combine array of x and y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent in Matlab would be:

```
data = [...
1   1   2   4;
1   3   2   6;
1   6   0   7]

x = (1:10).';
f = @(t) data(t,4)./(data(t,1) + data(t,2) + data(t,3) + x )

y = [ x f(1) x f(2) x f(3) ]
```

---

or even simpler:

```
N = 10;
f = @(t) [(1:N).' data(t,4)./(data(t,1) + data(t,2) + data(t,3) + (1:N).' )]

y = [ f(1) f(2) f(3) ]
```

the number in `f(...)` always indicates which row, respectively which `y` e.g. `y1`, `y2`, etc. you are calculating for each column of the output. The brackets `[...]` are concatenating the result.

Be aware that you need to use the [**element-wise division operator `./`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html)

---

Generalized for an `n x m` sized input array, but assuming that the `n`-column is always the last one of your input Matrix:

```
N = 10;
f = @(t) [(1:N).' data(t,end)./(sum( data(t,(1:end-1))) + (1:N).' )]

y = cell2mat(arrayfun(f, 1:size(data,1),'uni',0))
```

But in this case you should think about, if a more vectorized approach like [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28672498/2605073) might be more appropriate.

---

**result:**

```
y =

            1          0.8            1      0.85714            1        0.875
            2      0.66667            2         0.75            2      0.77778
            3      0.57143            3      0.66667            3          0.7
            4          0.5            4          0.6            4      0.63636
            5      0.44444            5      0.54545            5      0.58333
            6          0.4            6          0.5            6      0.53846
            7      0.36364            7      0.46154            7          0.5
            8      0.33333            8      0.42857            8      0.46667
            9      0.30769            9          0.4            9       0.4375
           10      0.28571           10        0.375           10      0.41176
```

Comment: guys did you see my desired output? because base on your code it doesn't match my desired output.

Comment: @nobel well, than you should clarify you question. You just gave one relation y = n/(a+b+c+d) - that's what we posted. I have no idea what you want to tell us on the second screenshot. Please clarify

Comment: @nobel The only code you have posted, you said doesn't work. Put in words or equations what you intend to get.

Comment: base on the picture, it must generate 3 arrays, and each array have size of 10x2 containing x and y values.

Comment: @nobel so what is `M`? and what is the relation between `y2` and `M`?

Comment: M is the array where my data was located. y1 =row 1, y2= row 2, y3 =row 3,and  in general y = n/( a +b +c +x).

Comment: yes it give the same output, but i suggest that your x must transform in column form instead of row form, thanks a lot by the way.

Comment: sir what is "@(t)" , means?

Comment: it creates an [**anonymous function**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) where an action is defined you want to repeat multiple times. in this cases `t` stands for the row number of your input and creates the columns for your output accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

[Vectorized approach](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) to get the desired output with another good case for [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to have the desired output for a **generic `m x n` sized** input array -

```
N = 10; %// Number of rows in the output
[m,n] = size(M) %// Get size

sum_cols = sum(M(:,1:n-1),2) %// sum along dim-2 until the second last column
sum_firstN = bsxfun(@plus,sum_cols,1:N) %// For each column-sum, add 1:N
out1 = bsxfun(@ldivide,sum_firstN,M(:,n)).'%//'# elementwise divide by last col
out = [repmat([1:N]',1,n); out1] %//'# Concatenate with starting columns of 1:N
out = reshape(out,N,[]) %// Reshape into desired shape
```

Code run for given `3 x 4` sized input array -

```
out =
    1.0000    0.8000    1.0000    0.8571    1.0000    0.8750
    2.0000    0.6667    2.0000    0.7500    2.0000    0.7778
    3.0000    0.5714    3.0000    0.6667    3.0000    0.7000
    4.0000    0.5000    4.0000    0.6000    4.0000    0.6364
    5.0000    0.4444    5.0000    0.5455    5.0000    0.5833
    6.0000    0.4000    6.0000    0.5000    6.0000    0.5385
    7.0000    0.3636    7.0000    0.4615    7.0000    0.5000
    8.0000    0.3333    8.0000    0.4286    8.0000    0.4667
    9.0000    0.3077    9.0000    0.4000    9.0000    0.4375
   10.0000    0.2857   10.0000    0.3750   10.0000    0.4118
```

Comment: it must generate 3 arrays, and each array have size of 10x2, containing x and y values

Comment: @nobel you just gave one equation for `y` and no equations for `y2` and `y2` so how should we know the relations?

Comment: sir y  is general equation for y1,y2,and y3: for example: y1 = n1/(a1 + b1 + c1 + x1), and so on...

Comment: yes this what the desired output i want, thanks a lot, sorry for my wrong statement of my problem .

Comment: @thewaywewalk Guys, Well done for getting that right. I know I'm thick but I still haven't understood the problem...

Comment: @kkuilla There is just one running variable and that is `x`. All other parameters are fixed for every column in the output and defined by the according row in the input. In Excel you would use the `$` sign to indicate fixed inputs.

Comment: @kkuilla Sum up first three columns, so for `M` as `3 x 4 sized` array you would have three such sums. Now, for each such sum add from 1 to 10. Thus, ending up with `3 x 10` sized array. Then perform elementwise division by the fourth column of M, which gives us the every other column of the desired output y1,y2, y3.

Comment: @nobel yes! Check out the edits for a generic `m x n` sized input array case.